# Python: sort specific elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of elements I want to sort, but I don't want to sort all of them, only those with a particular state. For example, let's say I have a list of peole:

```
lst = [Mary, John, Anna, Peter, Laura, Lisa, Steve]
```

Some of them have a job, let's say `[Anna, Lisa, Steve]`. I want to sort (ascending) these by the number of hours they work and move them to the beginning of the list, while keeping the rest in the exact same order. So let's say the number of hours they work is the following:

```
Anna.job.hours   # 10
Lisa.job.hours   # 5
Steve.job.hours  # 8
```

After the partial sort the list would look like this:

```
[Lisa, Steve, Anna, Mary, John, Peter, Laura]
```

Of course I could create two new lists out of the original one, sort the one I want to sort and the put them together again to achieve what I am after:

```
with_job = [person for person in lst if person.job]
without_job = [person for person in lst if not person.job]

with_job.sort(key=lambda p: p.job.hours)

lst = with_job + without_job
```

But I wonder if there is a straigthforward, Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: I find your way of doing Pythonic enough. You do not need the second list but other than that..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda p: p.job.hours if p.job else 999)
```

Comment: Does this solution keep the order for people without job?

Comment: Wait, now that I think about it, wouldn't this solution position the people without job at the beginning of the list, and not at the end as it is intended?

Comment: @dabadaba No, because of the minus sign `-p.job.hours`.

Comment: While this does put the people with a job in the beginning, it does sort them descending instead of ascending as per the given example.

Comment: Yes, it is descending (unfortunately).

Comment: Damn I didn't mean to include the minus sign in my original post, I actually want them in ascending order.

Comment: @dabadaba I've removed the minus for you. Also you need a large sentinel value to move all the unemployed to the end so I changed that too.

Comment: @Duncan is there no other approach than using a sentinel value? Reminds me too much of magic numbers.

Comment: @dabadaba, yes you could avoid the sentinal by using a key pair: `lst.sort(key=lambda p: (not p.job, p.job.hours if p.job else 0))` would sort the ones with a job first then the others and the 0 could be any constant value.

Comment: @dabadaba if makes the sort key a tuple The first element is False if p.job is set, True if p.job is not set so all the people with jobs sort first, then the ones without jobs. The second element then acts as a secondary key and sorts in order of the number of hours but only when needed to break the tie on the first element.